SAS largest correlation not equal to 1
Suppose I have dataset have which contains cross-correlations (obtained from a proc corr output):
  _NAME_    A      B      C
  A         1      0.2    0.8
  B         0.2    1      0.3
  C         0.8    0.3    1

I am trying to calculate the largest correlation value
 data want;
 set have;
 max_corr = max(of A B C);
 run;

Which produces:
  _NAME_    A      B      C     max_corr
  A         1      0.2    0.8   1
  B         0.2    1      0.3   1
  C         0.8    0.3    1     1

However, this value is 1 for each row, which is expected as the correlation across the diagonal is 1. How can I adjust the code to show the largest correlation not equal to 1?
For example, I'm looking for
  _NAME_    A      B      C     max_corr
  A         1      0.2    0.8   0.8
  B         0.2    1      0.3   0.3
  C         0.8    0.3    1     0.8


Question improvement suggestion: Don't have A, B and C both as column names and as name values. Also specify the expected result, i.e. provide a [mcve].

what type of result do you want to show? please give an example

@BusraEcemSakar - I've added example of what I want to show.

@jarlh - I've added example of expected results. The column names and name values are the same in the dataset, due to this being a cross-correlation output in SAS. It was generated from underlying data by proc corr data = input_data out=have (where=(_TYPE_ = "CORR")); var A B C; run;

thank you for your example, I posted my answer.

This doesn't seems to be SQL related, so I remove that tag.

You can use the largest function.
data corr;
   input _NAME_ $   A      B      C;
   max_corr = largest(2,of a b c);
   cards;
  A         1      0.2    0.8
  B         0.2    1      0.3
  C         0.8    0.3    1
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;



Seems you just want the second largest value?
data have;
input _NAME_ $ A B C;
datalines;
A 1 0.2 0.8 
B 0.2 1 0.3 
C 0.8 0.3 1 
;

data want;
   set have;
   max_corr = largest(2, of A--C);
run;


I suspect that what you really want is the largest correlation other than the self correlation (which is always 1).
In that case use an ARRAY and get the diagonal value out of the way.  You can always put the 1 back after finding the MAX.
data corr;
  input _NAME_ $ A B C ;
cards;
A   1      0.2    0.8
B   0.2    1      0.3
C   0.8    0.3    1
;;;;

data want;
  set corr;
  array _num_ _numeric_;
  _num_[_n_]=.;
  max_corr = max(of _num_[*]);
  length max_corr_var $32;
  max_corr_var = vname(_num_[whichn(max_corr,of _num_[*])]);
  _num_[_n_]=1;
run;

Result
                                                    max_
Obs    _NAME_     A      B      C     max_corr    corr_var

 1       A       1.0    0.2    0.8       0.8         C
 2       B       0.2    1.0    0.3       0.3         C
 3       C       0.8    0.3    1.0       0.8         A


You can use if statement, here is the code
data want;
    set have;
    
    /* Initialize max_corr as missing */
    max_corr = .;

    /* Compare each correlation and ignore the diagonal (where value = 1) */
    if A < 1 then max_corr = max(max_corr, A);
    if B < 1 then max_corr = max(max_corr, B);
    if C < 1 then max_corr = max(max_corr, C);
    
run;

